# How to promise the compiler that the generic type will have a certain property?

Tags: c#, generics

I'd like to use a certain operation for multiple variable types (both native and objects) so I'm using the generic return type as follows.

```
private Generic Field<Generic>(String field)
{
  if (BagOfJunk.Properties.Contains(field))
    return (Generic)BagOfJunk[field];
  return default(Generic);
}
```

This works well (and *BagOfJunk* is just a property of *this* from which I'm pulling out *Object* typed values). Now, during run-time, when a field isn't contained in the bag, I get the default value to be *null*. Hence, in the code, I need to perform a check as follows.

```
NumericType protoNumber = Field<NumericType>("beep");
int number = protoNumber != null ? protoNumber.Value : -1;

DateType protoDate = Field<DateType>("boop");
DateTime date = protoDate != null ? protoDate.Value : null;
```

I'd like to make the code more compact, so I tried to design a method that does the above four lines in one swoop, for a generic type. The result is below but, of course, it doesn't compile, because the type *GenericIn* isn't specific enough to have a property *Value*.

```
private GenericOut Field<GenericIn, GenericOut>(String field)
{
  GenericIn input = Field<GenericIn>(field);
  if (input != null)
    return (GenericOut)input.Value;
  return default(GenericOut);
}
```

How can I ensure the computer that my *GenericIn* isn't general - by promising that whatever stuff I'll shove into it, it'll always have the property *Value* in it?

## Edit

It should be emphasized that the type of *Value* needs to be generic ( equivalent to *GenericOut*). I noticed that I didn't stress that strongly enough. So the interface that can be used need to declare a property of general type like the following.

```
interface ObjectWithValue { public Generic Value { get; } }
```

Comment: Can you add an interface or abstract base type?

Comment: @JacobKrall Yes, I can. But that didn't solve my problem as far I could see. The return type from the property needs to be generic too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put that property in an interface (or a class) and use the generic constraint "where":

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
    public object Value { get; set; }
}

public class C<T> where T:IMyInterface
```

Comment: What would the property type be? It needs to be *GenericOut* but that isn't recognized by the compiler...

Comment: make it an object and cast it to GenericOut

Comment: Are you suggesting the the property is *public Object Value { get; }* and that I then cast said object's property *Value* to whatever I need in the method?

Comment: Ah, I was tricked by *interface ObjectWithValue { public Object Value { get; } }* not compiling. But that's because of the modifier *public* on the property! My bad. And as for the check of validity of type - how? Are you suggesting *as*-keyword? Or any better method?

Comment: Your suggestion compiles but when call *int n = Field<ProtoNumber, int>("beep");* I get error: there's no implicit conversion between *ProtoNumber* and *ObjectWithValue<int>*.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

You can use an interface and apply a where constraint on the type to implement that interface, like below:

```
interface IHasPropertyValue<TValue> {
  TValue Value { get; }
}

class MyType {
  public TValue Method<T, TValue>(T obj) where T : IHasPropertyValue<TValue> {
    return obj.Value;
  }
}
```

**EDIT: Modified the code above to make it more specific to the comment asked below.**

Comment: Yupp. Better now. However, the casting suggested by @zdradkodavev seems a bit shorter. Nevertheless, +1 for the generic type on the interface. Haven't use that before.   :)

Answer (score 1):

To build upon the answers so far, you need to create an interface that will be implemented by your `GenericIn` that will both guarantee that it has a property `Value` and that the property is of type `GenericOut`.

```
interface IHasValue<TOut>
{
    TOut Value { get; }
}

private TOut Field<TIn, TOut>(string field) where TIn : IHasValue<TOut>
{
    var input = Field<TIn>(field);
    return input == null ? default(TOut) : input.Value;
}
```

Comment: It compiles but when I add the actual call as follows: *int n = Field<ProtoNumber, int>("beep");*, I get complaints that there's no conversion between *ProtoNumber* and *ObjectWithValue<int>*.

Comment: Your `ProtoNumber`, `ProtoDate` etc. classes must implement an appropriate `ObjectWithValue<T>` for this to work.

Comment: Oh, that's not going to fly. I'm not the owner of these (can't request that they add the common interface). And there are likely to be more in the future. I guess it's a no-go...   :(